# Javascript debugging with Symfony2 in PhpStorm

Tags: javascript, symfony, phpstorm

I'm developing a Symfony2 application using PHPStorm IDE.

I can't seem to make it work. I've tried Javascript Debug for both local and remote with multiple parameters. Messages varies from "Remote URL isn't specified for  so breakpoint..." etc.

Best case scenario is that I would be able to debug my Javascript codes inside PHPStorm. Is this possible?

I'm also using AsseticBundle for my assets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use PHPStorm too but I only use it for coding, debuging is in browser..

So I would say it depends on if PHPStorm executes the app_dev.php and graps the output.
If you already have experience with PHPStorm (Debuging) you could answer this. I myself don't think so...

Hope I could help at least a little :)

Answer (score 0):

[JavaScript debugging is definitely possible](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/configuring-javascript-debugger.html) from the PhpStorm if you are using Chrome or Firefox browser. Debugging JavaScript and PHP at the same time is not supported at the moment.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But I can't make it work with Symfony2. =(

Comment: Contact support with the sample project and the steps to reproduce the problem.

Comment: It's not really I bug, I guess. Maybe something about how Symfony2 and assetic works. So it probably might just be a configuration problem.

Comment: You can debug PHP and JS at the same time, just start a PHP debug session, then start the JS debug session and close the php tab, because it works with a session variable it will still be debugging in the JS debug tab.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to set this up

1. Install the [JetBrains Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jetbrains-ide-support/hmhgeddbohgjknpmjagkdomcpobmllji)
2. In PHPStorm click the Run/Debug Configurations just to the left of the green bug near the top right
3. Add a Javascript Debug (using the plus sign)
4. In the URL box, just enter the URL of the page you're debugging (e.g. http://my.test/app_dev.php/route/here/not-there/3290), name the config, and apply
5. Add breakpoints in the js
6. Make sure dev tools is closed in the browser, then click the green bug (ensuring that the config named in 4 is chosen) and it will redirect to the page specified in 4.

The breakpoints will now be activated and are able to be stepped through (like xdebug). When it stops on a breakpoint it may be in a version of the original file with the file's name appended with a version number (this file is read-only). There is a button to the left hand side of the name where you can reload the read-only file being stopped at, after you have updated the actual (writable) file.